# No longer get battery notification or action

Tags: battery-life

I have an Asus n43jf laptop running Windows 7 64-bit.
The laptop is a little over a year old.

Up until very recently, when the battery would run low, I received a low battery notification, and if I continued without plugging in, I received a second "running on reserve power" notification. Finally, if I still didn't plug in, the laptop would hibernate. 
However, now I don't receive any notifications, and the laptop doesn't hibernate. 
When the battery gets low (just above 10%) the laptop will suddenly hard shut down. It acts as if the battery completely died, well before reaching 0%, and before reaching any of the  Low/Reserve/Critical battery levels.

What can I do to ensure that my laptop powers down more gracefully when running out of battery life, and make sure the % battery life remaining is accurate?

Comment: are you using some custom power plan? reset all power plans and switch some of the default windows power plans like "Power Saver"

Comment: I am using the standard "balanced" plan with default settings. I've looked at power options -> advanced settings, and the low battery level is 11%, low battery action is "do nothing", and low battery notification is "on"

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check the power plans of the Operating system.
If it's Windows 7 (the default OS for this computer), open Control Panel and select Power Options.
Check which power plan is selected, maybe it was changed accidently.
Choose one of the Preferred plans (Power saver for instance).
Check the advanced power settings and check the properties at the Battery section.

If these settings are OK, you should check the battery itself,
There are some free tools to check battery health online.

Hope this helps,
Shahar